Bourbaki: Algebra Chapter 2 §4. Proposition 1
The proposition states that for a $(B,A)$-bimodule $E$, a left $A$-module $F$, and a left $B$-module $G$:
$\mathrm{Hom}_{A}(F,\mathrm{Hom}_{B}(E,G))\cong \mathrm{Hom}_{B}(E\otimes_{A}F,G)$
However for this to be well-defined, Bourbaki supposes $\mathrm{Hom}_{B}(E,G)$ is a left $A$-module. But I can’t see how the above definitions endow it with this structure? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The structure is the "obvious" one, you may be mislead by the alternance left/right, but when it comes to the codomain everything is reversed.
Consider for $ a \in A, \, f:E \to G,$
$$a \cdot f: e \mapsto f(e\cdot a)$$
Then you have
$ (a’ \cdot (a \cdot f) ) (e)= (a \cdot f)(e \cdot a’) = f(e \cdot a’ \cdot a)= f(e \cdot a’a) = (a’a \cdot f) (e)$
Which means you have a well defined canonical left A-module on Hom(E,G), actually bimodules ${}_A \! X_B$ give two very important functors (for more info check morita equivalence): $X \otimes ?$ and $\hom(X,?)$, they give an adjunction to the derived level

Oh I see so the way the law of composition is defined is so that you can't distribute a before a'. I identified that this would be a problem for such a module being well-defined, but it seems that you've fixed that issue with your definition. Much appreciated.

Yeah, otherwise a left A module is given by a morphism of rings $A \to \mathrm{End}{\mathbf{Ab}} (M)$ for an abelian group M, and your right A-module here is à morphism $\rho: A^\text{op} \to \mathrm{End}{\mathbf{Ab}} (E)$ Hence your left A module is given by $\rho^*$ the precomposition
